# How i can take multiple (infinite) input through nodejs from user

Tags: node.js, express, module, routes, calculator

I have a question that how i can take a multiple input from user because "There can be an infinite number of query parameters!".. how can i  do that through javascript...

Going to calculator/multiply?firstParam=1&secondParam=2 Should respond with 2 Going to calculator/multiply?firstParam=1&secondParam=2&secondParam=4 Should respond with 8.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;
```

//how i can take as much "nums" values as user wants instead of only two nums:
    app.get('/:operator/num1/num2', function(req,res){

```
var operator = req.params.operator;
var num1 = parseInt(req.query.num1);
var num2 = parseInt(req.query.num2);
var result;

switch(operator){
    case "addition":
    result = add(num1, num2);
    break;

    case "subtraction":
    result = subtract(num1, num2);
    break;

    case "multiplication":
    result = multiply(num1, num2);
    break;

    case "division":
    result = divide(num1, num2);
    break;

    default:
    result = "Sorry, please enter a valid operator!"
}

function add(a, b){
    return a + b

}

function subtract(a, b){
    return a - b
}

function multiply(a, b){
    return a * b
}

function divide(a, b){
    return a / b
}

res.json(result);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.send("hello! please type some math y'all")
});

//listener
app.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log("App listening on PORT:" + PORT);
});
```